# openldap group owner write to own group

Tags: permissions, openldap

I Just installed openldap and phpldapadmin om my linux box and it works fine.

I'm a complete newbee to openldap.. I want to be able to add users in phpldapadmin with write (add/modify/delete) permissions to their own group. I can add a user as an owner to a group and he can log in and view everything but still that user cannot write to the group.

How do I modify permissions so the owner of a group have full write permissions to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why should a user be able to write to his own group?

Comment: It makes sense. Why should he not?